# PHP - Obtener el nombre de una propiedad de un "new \stdClass"

Tags: php, php7

Supongamos que tengo un objeto en PHP en donde por supuesto cada propiedad tiene un nombre.

Si estuviera en JavaScript sería suficiente con utilizar el [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) para obtener cada nombre de propiedad.

Pero no encuentro una manera equivalente de hacer eso en PHP.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que busco:

```
object(stdClass) (4) {
 ["ID"]=>
 string(38) "920fghgf-5179-11ed-5464-0e8890896d214b"
 ["Createdat"]=>
 string(19) "2022-10-21 16:50:20"
 ["hello"]=>
 NULL
 ["Nombre"]=>
 string(11) "Hello World"
}
```

En este caso me interesa obtener un array con los nombres `ID`, `Createdat`, `hello` y `Nombre`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php

Comment: ¿Las propiedades se definen en tiempo de ejecución?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré una [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240163/15385861) bastante útil para solucionar este problema.

Allí se sugiere en primer lugar transformar el `new \stdClass` en un array mediante la función de PHP llamada [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

Luego ya es más sencillo acceder a los nombres de las propiedades, ya que para eso nos puede servir el [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

De esta manera, lo puedo llevar a la práctica con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
        $hello_world = new \stdClass;

        $hello_world->ID = "920fghgf-5179-11ed-5464-0e8890896d214b";
        $hello_world->Createdat = "2022-10-21 16:50:20";
        $hello_world->hello = NULL;
        $hello_world->Nombre = "Hello World";

        $hello_world = get_object_vars($hello_world);
        $arr_fields = [];

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($hello_world as $item) 
        {
            array_push($arr_fields, array_keys($hello_world)[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
```

Reutilizando el caso anterior que puse en mi pregunta, lo que hago es:

1. Transformar a array el objeto: `$hello_world = get_object_vars($hello_world)`
2. Inicializar un nuevo array llamado `$arr_fields` que guardará todos los nombres de las propiedades.
3. Recorrer el `$hello_world` mediante un `foreach` e ir recolectando cada nombre de propiedad con el `array_keys` al que le tenemos que especificar un indice mediante el `$i`.

De esa forma replicamos el mismo funcionamiento del  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` de JavaScript.

El código completo [se puede probar aquí](https://paiza.io/projects/7eDMx8mQYKGfBr78ObdwDA)

**ACTUALIZADO:**

Con todo, descubrí que aun podemos optimizar todavía más el código dándole un propósito más certero al `foreach` y prescindiendo completamente del `$i`, el `get_object_vars()` y el `array_keys()`.

Y es de la siguiente manera:

```
$hello_world = new \stdClass;

$hello_world->ID = "920fghgf-5179-11ed-5464-0e8890896d214b";
$hello_world->Createdat = "2022-10-21 16:50:20";
$hello_world->hello = NULL;
$hello_world->Nombre = "Hello World";

$arr_fields = [];
foreach ($hello_world as $key => $value ) 
{
    array_push($arr_fields, $key);
}
```

De esta forma, con el `$key` accedemos a cada nombre de propiedad del objeto lo que nos permitirá ingresarlo a un nuevo array.

Así obtenemos el mismo resultado anterior con menos pasos.

Se puede [probar el código aquí](https://paiza.io/projects/EZLtM-Sd9RQFyQpm2C6ioQ).

Comment: No sería más sencillo que declararas directamente un array con las claves y valores que necesitas? Parece poco util crear un objeto dinámico para luego extraer las propiedades como claves, cuando puedes hacerlo directamente...

Comment: Por otra parte, podrías serializar el objeto a json, y luego deserializarlo como array

Comment: En este ejemplo podría tener sentido lo que me dices. Pero si partimos de la base en la que estamos trabajando con un objeto que ya viene de la base de datos así, entonces sería necesario transformarlo debido a que no encontré otra manera más simple. En cuenta a la alternativa de hacerlo JSON, te invito a que agregues un ejemplo en una respuesta con esa posibilidad.

Comment: No es necesario marear tanto al objeto, usa la [*Conversión de Tipos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversión_de_tipos): `$arr_fields = array_keys((array)$hello_world);`.

Comment: @Sal por favor agrega una respuesta más para demostrar tu punto reutilizando mi ejemplo. Así podremos ver lo que sugieres en la práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Como posible alternativa, y considerando el objeto `$hello_world` de la respuesta anterior, se podría hacer una serialización a json y luego deserializar a array de la siguiente manera:

`json_decode(json_encode($hello_world), true);`

Esto te devuelve un array clave-valor, donde la clave es el nombre de la propiedad, con su valor correspondiente.

Entonces, todo el código quedaría así:

```
$hello_world = new \stdClass;

$hello_world->ID = "920fghgf-5179-11ed-5464-0e8890896d214b";
$hello_world->Createdat = "2022-10-21 16:50:20";
$hello_world->hello = NULL;
$hello_world->Nombre = "Hello World";

$array = json_decode(json_encode($hello_world), true);
```

Se puede [probar aquí](https://paiza.io/projects/SAzbiuaUQodHJmfXeUmulA).

Comment: Con esta alternativa, veo un poco más difícil agregar más lógica en el medio al redefinir una propiedad y otra. Además, la idea en realidad era tener un array limpio que almacene los nombres de cada propiedad y no sus respectivos valores. Recuerda que tiene que ser lo más parecido posible al resultado de usar `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` en JavaScript.

Comment: No veo el problema de añadir lógica. Lo que estás haciendo es crear un objeto (haces antes toda la lógica de crearlo) y luego lo serializamos a json, y luego a array. Si lo que quieres es solo las propiedades, únicamente tienes que hacer sobre este resultado un array_keys. Esto último te devolverá un listado de las propiedades.

Comment: Si se le agrega el `array_keys()` sí cumpliría con los requerimientos de la pregunta. Quizás puedas editar tu respuesta y agregarlo para poder completarla.